# Efficient filtering on type ignore

Tags: postgresql, indexing, case, filtering, where-clause

I have a set of data (dozens of columns from different table in different type) and i want to filter them depending on the user's input.

So what i have is a postgress function which has for example two parameters one is array of text which will have the user input (An array of strings) and another boolean one which indicates whether all of them should be in or not inside the where clause.

- The first question is :

  **What if we have alot of columns to compare with them , we will have then a big and ugly where condition! Is there any other better casea that we can add them inside a big array and compare the two arrays together or call them from another function?**

Example of the inputs and how the results should match:

**Keywords:** Agent AND Mark AND 27

**Data:** id | position | name | age

15423 | Real Estate Agent | Mark Miller | 27 --> 3/3 in position, name, age --> **TRUE**

2754 | Secret Agent | Markus Smith | 43 --> 3/3 in id, position, name --> **TRUE**

4567 | Facility Agent | Sam Wilson | 55 --> 1/3 in position --> **FALSE**

The postgresql function:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.filter(
"FilterText" text[],
"trueORFalse" boolean)
 RETURNS record AS
 $BODY$

select DISTINCT t1.id,
t2.position ,
t3.name ,
t4 age

FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN  table2 AS t2 on t1.id = t2.fk_id 
LEFT JOIN  table3 AS t3  on t3.fk_id = t2.fk_id 
LEFT JOIN  table4 AS t4  on t4.fk_id = t3.fk_id 
WHERE 
t2.position like ANY($1) 
   -- (AND - OR) depending on the second paramater value $2 ?           
t3.name like ANY($1) 
   -- (AND - OR) depending on the second paramater value $2 ?           
t4 age like ANY($1) 

$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql STABLE SECURITY DEFINER
 COST 100;
 ALTER FUNCTION public.filter(text[], boolean)
 OWNER TO table_rights_in_functions;
 GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.filter(text[], boolean) TO public;
 GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.filter( text[], boolean) TO 
 table_rights_in_functions;
```

- Another question is :

  **How to add a CASE WHEN condition to check the second paramter to 
  determine the AND - OR cases inside the where clause?**

Finally my postgres version is 9.6.8

Comment: Note the condition: `WHERE 
t2.position like ANY($1) ` will effectively turn the `LEFT JOIN t2` into a plain JOIN. (similar for t3 and t4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found these two magic functions: to_tsvector , to_tsquery which compare two array of strings and for Controlling Text Search.
More info:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/textsearch-controls.html

so for example

we have to create new function:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_concat_ws(text, VARIADIC text[])
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS 'SELECT array_to_string($2, $1)';
```

then in the where-clause:

```
  WHERE  to_tsvector('simple', f_concat_ws(' ', t2.position,t3.name,t4.age))
  @@ to_tsquery('simple', $2);
```